# How to enter cell last modified timestamp (using a formula) in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to achieve the following but without the use of VBA, I have found a [formula](https://excelweez.com/how-to-timestamp-in-excel-when-cell-changes/) which works if the cell is empty (but not modification) anyone knows how to achieve this?

[image: this picture]

Comment: It cannot be done with formula.  It will require vba.

Comment: Even the link's suggestion has many drawbacks beyond it only capturing the first change.  It requires that all users of the workbook set their settings to allow circular references, and those settings are Excel wide not just this workbook.